# VueJS: <template> vs <div> or related for grouping elements for conditional rendering

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-directives

In Vue.js, if you want to conditionally render multiple elements via a `v-if/v-else-if` directive you can wrap them inside `<template>` tags and apply the directive to the `<template>` tag, as explained [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Conditional-Groups-with-v-if-on-lt-template-gt). However, you can also do the same with `<div>` tags wrapping the multiple elements. **Are there any noticeable performance benefits to using `<template>` over `<div>` or any other similar native HTML5 tag?**

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I doubt there is a performance change but a big difference is that the `<template>` node *does not appear in the DOM*.

This is an important distinction especially when grouping children that are the only valid node types for their parent such as list items, table rows, etc:

This is valid:

```
<ul>
  <template v-if="something">
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
  </template>
</ul>
```

This is not:

```
<ul>
  <div v-if="something">
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ah, I see. The example of conditionally rendering lists is a great one!

Answer (score 8):

I know that the question is quite old, but I found out one more thing

if you use divs - your *div* will be in DOM, but empty, if v-if is false and it can make some spaces looks like margins

if you use *template* - you don't have anything in DOM and it just don't appear